# Serverless Framework with custom packaging

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) and I can't seem to package my functions the way I want.

My current folder directory looks like this:

```
service/
  serverless.yml
  function1/
    package.json
    handler.js
    node_modules/
      ...
  function2/
    handler.py
    requirements.txt
    venv/
      ...
```

Is it possible to cherry pick which folder I want to include in the zip file and also specify the corresponding destination path inside the zip file?

For example, I want to zip everything inside `function1` folder but all of them should be at root level of the zip file. Right now all the generated files are in a folder called `function1` in the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packaging does not work this way ([docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/)). You can't specify the file tree that will be saved inside the zip. You can only specify what you will *include* or *exclude* in this zip.

In the [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging#artifact) link, you can see an option to use an **Artifact**. In this case, you could develop your own code to zip using exactly the rules that you want and output a zip file to be used by the Serverless Framework. It is possible, but I hope that you don't need this.

Why do you want to move the contents of the folder "function1" to the root level? Maybe your true question is: **"How can I reference my Lambda function that is located at another folder?"**. If this is the case, you could use the following in the **serverless.yml** file:

```
service: test

functions:
  func1:
    handler: function1/handler.func1
  func2:
    handler: function1/handler.func2
```

The syntax is **folder/filename.function**.

Another solution would be to create one **serverless.yml** file for each folder. The problem with this approach is that you would not be able to access the function2 from the function1.

Comment: I guess it's fine if it's a nodejs function, but what about a python function? The solution I found is more like a hack than an official solution. http://forum.serverless.com/t/aws-python-function-dependencies-load/451/5

Comment: @LingxiaoXia, at your link, el0ck said that you don't need to manually zip the package. The recommended approach is to install 64bit libraries (because it will run on a 64bit machine) and modify the os.path of your Python function.

Comment: Yes and I consider that a hack because it requires code change. Configuration changes are ok but code change doesn't seem that sustainable.

Comment: Ok, the only option that you still have is to create a build process that will zip the file and use the **artifact** property. Currently, the Serverless Framework don't help you to select how files will be distributed inside the zip.