# How do I reference a function that is not in the root folder using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using the Serverless Framework 1.x and I want to define my **serverless.yml** to reference a function that is located in another folder (not in the root level).

For example, in the following folder structure, I want to reference a `handler()` function that is defined in a **function1.js** file inside the folder **functions**.

```
serverless.yml
functions/
  function1.js
  function2.js
  function3.js
package.json
node_modules/
  ..
```

All examples that I see consider the following basic scenario where the file is in the root:

```
serverless.yml
handler.js
```

Where the **serverless.yml** file is defined by:

```yaml
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
```

Comment: I've self-answered this question in the hope to help future readers. This question was inspired by [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415688/serverless-framework-with-custom-packaging).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Serverless Framework access functions inside other folders using the following syntax:

```
folder/filename.function
```

So, if we have a file named **function1.js** with a function `handler()` that we want to execute when our Lambda function is invoked, we use the following definition inside the **serverless.yml** file:

```
service: example

functions:
  func1:
    handler: functions/function1.handler
  func2:
    handler: functions/function2.handler
```

The same would apply for multiple levels of folders:

```
folder/folder/folder/filename.function
```

Comment: what about the other way around, looking at directory behind. eg: ../../../functions.function1.handler.

will this work